# How to serve fresh bao buns

Tags: baking, steaming

So I would like to make bao buns fresh on my food truck. What would be the best method of steaming. I proof, roll out and proof again then steam for 10 minutes. I guess I can't steam them to order, what would be the best way to go about this. Should I just make as many as I can in the morning? what would be the best way to store them to keep them soft and moist. Should I re-steam before serving?

I appreciate any ideas. Thanks!

Comment: Cooler box is a reasonable choice actually. Or you can put your steam on low and keep steaming it, which shouldn't do any harm for a hour or two.

Answer (score 5):

Bao are very forgiving.  Food truck aside for a moment, as I don't know what kind of equipment you are carrying, bao can be prepared, steamed, cooled, then frozen.  They can be re-steamed directly from the freezer prior to service with no problem.  You can also make them on the day they will be served. You can steam, cool/refrigerate, then re-steam...or time it so that they are in the steamer during service. Depending on your volume, you can just keep a steamer stocked with the right number of buns.  They can hang out there for a while with no problem.

Comment: There's a restaurant that I go that has them wrapped in plastic wrap in a chilled display case.  When they're ordered, they heat them up.  I assume by steaming, based on the time it takes.  And for takeout, they give them to you still wrapped in plastic  (with some paper underneath).  I assume they steam them, wrap in plastic (possibly after coolong some), then chill down 'til ordered